# How to get User id using Passport Token in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3, laravel-5.5, laravel-passport

How to get Current User Id from posted Passport Auth Token in Laravel. I use

```
$request->user()->id;
```

is correct method for get current user id in laravel API

Comment: Please check https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/get-the-user-id-in-laravel-passport

Comment: You could do `auth()->user()->id` which would return the id of the current authenticated user

Answer (score 4):

To get user id, you can use as below: 
Detailed you can see [Reference](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/get-the-user-id-in-laravel-passport).

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user()->id;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

`auth('api')->user()` returns the authenticated user (or null if the user is not logged on) - even if middleware is not used.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code.

```
   use Auth;    
    class MyController extends Controller {    
       public function myFunc(){    
          dd(Auth::user()->id);    
       }    
    }
```