# laravel 8 how to get user id using bearer token

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-sanctum

I am working with laravel 8 and I need to access one of the API routes whether using a token or without a token
for example I have a post page and if user is logged in I want to check if he like the post or not but if he is not logged in I just display the post.

I write the following code but I am getting an error 500

```
$bearer=$request->header('Authorization');
if(isset($bearer)){
            
            $fav=UserFav::where('user_id',request()->user()->id)->where('project_id',$id)->get();
            if(!$fav->isEmpty())
            $is_fav=true;
        }
```

the error message is

> Attempt to read property id on null

I understand the message it says the request()->user() is returning null
and that's because the route is not in sanctum middleware

but the problem if I put the route to sanctum middleware  I will not be able to access it as guest
so how I can get the user id or user according to bearer token sent in header ??

Comment: I don't think this works when using the api, the goal of using REST is that every request doesn't know about the previous request.

Comment: so what is your suggestion  for this case ?

Comment: You will have to put it in the request, when you make it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48419941/how-to-get-user-id-using-passport-token-in-laravel

Answer (score 2):

I'm using passport instead of sanctum, and the way I do is

```
auth('api')->user()->id
```

or

```
$request->user()->id
```

Comment: i am looking for same result without using sanctum or passport

Answer (score 0):

Auth::check will give you if the user is authenticated, even if you're using brearer token

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

$is_fav = false;
if(Auth::check()) {
    $is_fav = UserFav::where('user_id',Auth::user()->id)
                 ->where('project_id',$id) 
                 ->exists();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
if(!empty(request()->user())){ // Define user logged in
  $fav=UserFav::where('user_id',request()->user()->id)->where('project_id',$id)->get();
} else {
  $fav=UserFav::->where('project_id',$id)->get();
}

if(!$fav->isEmpty()) {
  $is_fav=true;
}
```

Comment: The question is "laravel 8 how to get user id using bearer token" how is this getting the user id?

Comment: You can get the user with request helper laravel it's also work for laravel passport / sanctum, Or if you want to make simple use Auth Helper

Comment: @Ryヅ request()->user() always return null if route is not in sanctum middle ware

Comment: https://laracasts.com/index.php/discuss/channels/laravel/get-user-by-token